# Typescript: How to redefine static method signature of class

Tags: typescript

I have an external module `some-module` which implements class:

```
export declare class Some<T> {
   ...
   static create<T>(): Some<T>;
   map<U>(x: U): Some<U>;
}

export default Some
```

I want to redefine signature of some methods for my project, so I do:

```
declare module 'some-module' {

  interface Some<T> {
     static create<T extends number>(): Some<T>; // this doen't have any effect
     map<U extends number>(x: U): Some<U>;// here I can redefine method
  }
}
```

It works, now `some.map` has new signature. But I don't get how to I can redefine signature of static method `create`? Is it possible?

So I could do:

```
import {Some} from 'some-module'

const some = Some.create()
some.map // <- this has new signature
Some.create // <- this has old signature
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `namespace` keyword to merge a function to your class.

```
declare module 'some-module' {
  export class Some<T> {
    map<U extends number>(x: U): Some<U>;
  }

  export namespace Some {
    const create: <T extends number>() => Some<T>;
  }
}
```

It's effectively the same as having a static method.

Usage:

```
import { Some } from 'some-module';

new Some();
Some.create();
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. So with namespace I can add static method, but old definition is not overriden.

Comment: Are you _augmenting_ that class or _overriding_ it? If the file in which you keep your `declare module 'some-module' {` definition has no import/export statements, it will override the definition completely.

Comment: `declare module` is in `d.ts` file that is inteded to override definitions of external module, in external module class is described in it's `.d.ts` as shown in OP.